# Create function componente HOC with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Im tryng to create a simple HOC to add SideMenu to my react FC's not sure wiht im doing wrong

the HOC :

```
const withSideBar = <P extends object>(
  WrappedComponent: React.ComponentType<P>
): React.FC => {
  const [hidden,setHidden] = useState(false)
  return <div className="main-container">
    <div className="container">
      <SideMenu hidden={hidden} />
      <div className="column-9">
        <NavHeader callBack={() => setHidden(!hidden)} />
        <div className="main">
          <WrappedComponent />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <Footer />
  </div>
}

export default withSideBar
```

Home

```
const Home: React.FC = () => {
  return <div>HOME</div>
}

export default withSideBar(Home)
```

the error is :

```
Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'FC<{}>'.
  Type 'Element' provides no match for the signature '(props: { children?: ReactNode; }, context?: any): ReactElement<any, any>
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You're typing the return value of `withSideBar` as `React.FC` but you're not returning a function, you're returning an Element.  Typescript will infer the return type for you.  Without seeing all your code, you can at least move past that error by just removing the `React.FC` return type:

```
const withSideBar = <P extends object>(
  WrappedComponent: React.ComponentType<P>
) => {
  const [hidden,setHidden] = useState(false)
  return <div className="main-container">
    <div className="container">
      <SideMenu hidden={hidden} />
      <div className="column-9">
        <NavHeader callBack={() => setHidden(!hidden)} />
        <div className="main">
          <WrappedComponent />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <Footer />
  </div>
}
```